# Conversion of dataframe into a realRatingMatrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to convert a data-frame that contains three columns username, itemnumber or itemID and the rating. The datatype of the three columns are mentioned below.

```
>             userID          itemid         rating
               <chr>           <int>          <dbl>
```

I found the method to convert a data-frame into a realRatingMatrix when all the columns are numeric. However, I was unable to find a function to convert this data-frame which contains both character and numeric datatype.
Can someone please suggest any solution to convert a data-frame to realRatingMatrix.

Comment: how did you convert data frame into realReatingMatrix?

Comment: Conversion of a dataframe **with all variables with datatype as _int_** can be converted into realRatingMatrix is a two step process. Firstly, converting the dataframe into a matrix with as.matrix(). Secondly, converting the matrix to a realRatingMatrix with as(m, "realRatingMatrix) function.

Answer (score 0):

as(data.frame,"realRatingMatrix")

Answer (score 0):

Couple of steps and this worked for me:

```
m$userID <- as.factor(m$userID)
m$itemID <- as.factor(m$itemID)
m$rating <- as.numeric(m$rating)

m <- as(m, "realRatingMatrix")
```

I needed my  rating to be numeric, not sure if double works but I don't see a reason it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late but i found a solution. Instead of converting the dataframe to a realRatingMatrix, assign the returned expression of the as function to a temporary variable.

So just a `temp <- as(data.frame,"realRatingMatrix")` would be enough. `class(temp)` would give you output - `[1] "realRatingMatrix"`. There is no need to convert the char fields to factors.